# Stored Procedures in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, stored-procedures

> The ADO.NET Entity Framework (EF)
>   allows you to map stored procedures to
>   functions that return typed results in
>   the conceptual model.

Does Stored procedures needed in Entity framework ?

 We using Linq to entities to querying data , so what is the usage of stored procedures ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a situation where you're either forced to use SPs or need to execute some SQL that is otherwise outside of the scope of what EF can do for you.  For example, if you have to use a specific collation to order your results, EF doesn't support that.  I had this same exact scenario come up.  For that specific functionality I created a stored procedure which I mapped to an existing entity.